# Best way to calculate 24 hours window of Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger

I notice Facebook Messenger Policy stated that the Page won't be able to send the user a message after 24 hours session/window ended.

I am trying to iterate over a list of Facebook User PSIDs, and send some update to them. For those users that are outside of 24 hours window, I would not want to send any message to them.

I have researched over the Facebook Messenger Graph API and found few of the API are suitable for use to calculate.

1. To get the user conversation ID
   `https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/<PAGE_ID>/conversations?platform=messenger&user_id=<USER_ID>`
2. To get the user message list containing Message ID
   `https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/<CONVERSATION_ID>?fields=messages`
3. To get the user specific message
   `https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/<MESSAGE_ID>?fields=from,to,message`

By using this method, I am able to know when is the last message sent by the user. But there are downside to this approach because just for a single user, I have to call multiple APIs and it might reach the Facebook Messenger Rate Limit.

Does anyone here have better solution in order to check this problem?

Comment: Record the info when you got the last message already at the time you are getting it ...? Then you don't need to make API calls to try and figure that out later on.

Comment: Because I am trying to send every customer their invoices after they made order, can I use message tags - POST_PURCHASE_UPDATE instead? For this case, I don't have to worry about the 24 hours limitation

Comment: _"Because I am trying to send every customer their invoices after they made order"_ - not sure how that justifies a "because." Were those orders made _in_ messenger in the first place? Then you should have the timestamp of that. And if they weren't - well then you would have no 24h window here to begin with. POST_PURCHASE_UPDATE sounds like it was made for use cases such as yours though.

Comment: Customers made order from a third party app I subscribed to that link to my Facebook Page & messenger. Sometimes customer do not know how to access their shopping cart to see their invoice, so I would want to send them personally in messenger.

Comment: _"Customers made order from a third party app"_ - so _your_ messenger implementation is not involved in that part in the first place? If there was no message from the customer to your page - then you would not have any "24 hour window" to begin with.